# Frame ticks go missing when I give the option ScalingFunctions

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I've been attempting to use `ScalingFunctions` to scale the y-axis of my plot by $10^{10}$, however when I do, the frame ticks disappear and I'm not sure how to get it back. Currently I have 3 data files which I plot with

```
ListLinePlot[
  {ClFKdata1[[All, {1, 2}]], ClFKdata2[[All, {1, 2}]], ClFKdata3[[All, {1, 2}]]}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", {10^10*# &, # &}}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> {Large, Black}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  ImageSize -> 1000, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, 2, 4, 6}, None}, {All, None}}, 
  FrameStyle -> 
    {{"", Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]}, 
     {"", Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]}}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

to try and get ticks at 0, 2, 4 and 6, but I get

[image]

I've also tried `All` and `Automatic`, but that doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation:

[image]

a list should consist of inverse functions, and yours are not inverses. Since you didn't provide data, here is one I made up, where I've corrected the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) so that inverses are used:

```
ListLinePlot[
    {
    Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,0,100,1}],
    Table[{x,Cos[x]},{x,0,100,1}],
    Table[{x,x},{x,0,100,1}]
    },
    ScalingFunctions->{"Log", {10^10*#&,# 10^-10&}},
    Frame->True
]
```

[image]

Of course, in this example, linearly modifying the scaling functions for the y-axis doesn't do anything.